# Cannot start MySql server

Tags: mysql

I have problem starting the MySql server.
The log says:

```
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
111220 16:16:43  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './mysql-bin.000028' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry
 in 60 secs
```

After I check the disk - it says it's full.
So, after searching for solution - I found that I need to purge the binary log.
However, in order to purge - I need to start the MySql server, but all the spacein the disk is taken by the binary log, so I can't start...
It's also not advised to simply delete the binary logs. 
So, I am kind of stuck.
Can't run the mysql to purge logs and can't purge logs because can't run server.
Any help? :)

Edit: The disk contains only the logs, there's nothing else.

Comment: Is there nothing else on the disk you can move somwhere else temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is ext[2|3|4] you can use tune2fs to set the portion of the disk reserved for root to 0, giving you maybe enough breathing room to start the server

this would be tune2fs -m 0 /dev/whatever (after unmounting, ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the mysql server with the option --expire_logs_days=, it should delete the log and older than  days directory at startup.

bye
Gianluca

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like  --expire_logs_days just specifies the frequency at which logs are rolled. But it doesn't make the mysql to roll the logs immediately.

Comment: Well, the documentation report: "Possible removals happen at startup and when the binary log is flushed.", so I suppose that if you use something like mysqld --expire_log_days=10 it remove all the binlog file older that 10 days

Comment: Maybe it happens after the startup, but since the startup fails, it has not effect.

Comment: You can try a dirty trick: move some of the log file to another directory (say /tmp) on a partition where there is some free space, then create a symbolic link to the moved file in the original directory. This way you should free some space and be able to start MySql with the --expire_logs_days switch or simply purge some log files from the directory with the "PURGE BINARY LOGS" command from the mysql shell, see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html] for the full documentation. After freeing some more space, you can stop MySql and eventually move back the files